# C# WPF: Geometric Operations

Tags: c#, wpf

I know WPF supports *some* geometric operations, but I'm wondering if it supports others.

I know it supports:

- The bounding box of a polygon/path or collection of a polygons/paths.
- Determine whether a given polygon/path lies within another polygon/path.

Does it support:

- Unions
- Intersections
- The ability to determine if two shapes share a common border

Comment: I think you're trying to find out of WPF supports some sort of polygon-edge/vertex optimalization, or if it's easy to write one, if so, please ask that question :). Because at the moment I don't think it's 100% clear what use a Union or Intersection would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a union or intersection of two geometries, use a `CombinedGeometry` and set the [`GeometryCombineMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.geometrycombinemode.aspx) to `Union` or `Intersect`.

If you're just trying to find out if two geometries intersect, look at [`StrokeContainsWithDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615709.aspx) and [`FillContainsWithDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607451.aspx).